# How to use css to style id within many divs

Tags: html, css

I am styling a wordpress child-theme and the code below is what I am dealing with. each div is within the previous. It ends with a div then a h2. the last two our my additions to the code. I want to style the text in the h2 tag. when I use a id or class and go into the style sheet and type

```
 #tag { 
        **Styles i want here** 
      }
```

or do it as a class, it wont register. How do I format it? I left the div and h2 without an id or class because idk how to format it like I said

```
<head>
 <body>
  <div clas="main-container">
   <div id="page">
    <div class="content">
     <aside class="sidebar c-4-12">
      <div id="sidebars">
       <div class="sidebar_list">
        <div>
         <h2>TEXT HERE I WANT TO STYLE</h2>
```

Comment: "it wont register" — Why would it? The h2 doesn't have an id and it isn't a member of a class. No element has the id `tag`.

Comment: did you read what I said? I stated that I took the id and class tags off because I wasn't sure if I was doing it right so whatever the need to be you can make them that way 

" I left the div and h2 without an id or class because idk how to format it like I said"

Comment: We can't tell if you are "doing it right" if you don't show us a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. If you need an introduction to CSS, then there are plenty out there, like [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started).

Comment: What ever happen to being fresh at something and asking for help

Comment: sorry I didn't know that this website was for experts only. I'll keep that in mind when posting again

Answer (score 1):

ID of element should be unique. And because it's unique, you just have a CSS codes like below:

```
#your-id {
  // Your css codes
}
```

It should work, but we should not use ID for styling element, class name instead.

In your case, your codes should be something like:

```
.content h2 {
  // your css codes
}
```

Somehow, your h2 tag have a styling with higher priority. Then you can use `!important` in each of properties. But it's not a best practice for us.

```
.content h2 {
  color: #fff !important; //Example code
}
```

By the way, I see wrong syntax in your code: `clas="main-container"`, please correct `class` attribute

Thanks